# Launch a program running file matching string

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Hello i'm trying to make a program for my friend that will launch PowerPoint in slideshow mode.
It works by typing in a name into a textbox and then add the rest for the user. The problem is that it always fails finding the target and I need some help.

Could somebody review the code and fix the problem(s)?

Also keep it simple for the user please.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim fileName As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim Command As String = Chr(34) + "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.EXE\" + Chr(34) + " /S "

Sub Run()
    Try
        filePath = (Command + "powerpoints\" + fileName + ".pptx")
        Process.Start(filePath)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Beep()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    fileName = TextBox1.Text
    Run()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: it fails to find **what** powerpoint.exe or the pptx file?  I am pretty sure Powerpoint doesnt store pptx in a child folder in `Program Files`.

Comment: I would not have posted it otherwise. Matt

Comment: I don't know actually. I have not been able to figure out. Plutonix

Comment: @user3613307 Welcome to StackOverflow! Does your program display the message box that you've put after the `Beep()` line? What does it say? Instead of `ex.Message`, try the same code but with `ex.ToString()` which will give you more details about the error. Posting those details here in full may help us help you further :)

Comment: Process.Start() as used will only work for filenames, not command lines. You would need to use the more powerful ProcessStartInfo()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2 suggestions.  First, are you received any exception when you run this code?  If so, can you please post those details?  If possible, debug and step through the code to determine what line the code is failing on.  That will help determine what "target" is failing.

Secondly, if you're walking blindly on some of this code, try checking out some other examples online (if you haven't already).  A quick Google on this topic provided this (courtesy of http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/vb_start_slide_show.html)

```
Sub StartSlideShow(ByVal FileName  As String)
     Dim PPT  As Object
     Dim Pres  As Object

     On Error Resume Next

     Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
     Set Pres = PPT.Presentations.Open(FileName, False, False,  False)
     If Pres.SlideShowWindow  Is Nothing Then
         Pres.SlideShowSettings.Run
     End If
End Sub
```

It seems relatively straightforward, so hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: This is VBA/macro syntax. The question refers to VB.NET in both syntax and tags. It also does not involve any interop code.

Comment: Your answer actually helped me finish the program. Thanks. I had to do a slight refit but that's all.